# Android start static app shortcut

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, android-package-managers, android-static-shortcuts

Past few days I have been trying to figure out how to start app shortcuts added in Android API 25 and I have been somewhat successful. Starting some shortcuts like Google Play Music's work without problem I'm guessing because these shortcuts are starting activities with *action.MAIN* and *category.LAUNCHER* or exported, but other activities throw *"java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent"* which seems reasonable as well. This seems dooable since apps like Pixel Launcher, Sesame Shortcuts etc. can do this, there must be some special intent flag or something. I even tried catching shortcut intent inside my app and replicating it but no success

Here is example of how I do this for Google Chrome's "New Tab" shortcut:

```
val componentName = ComponentName("com.android.chrome", "org.chromium.chrome.browser.LauncherShortcutActivity")
val intent = Intent(action)
intent.component = componentName
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME)
startActivity(intent)
```

I got these values from activityInfo metaData which can be fetched with *PackageManager*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code to list all available shortcuts and then launch whatever the first shortcut is (just as an example):

```
val launcherApps = context.getSystemService(Context.LAUNCHER_APPS_SERVICE) as LauncherApps

val shortcutQuery = LauncherApps.ShortcutQuery()
// Set these flags to match your use case, for static shortcuts only,
// use FLAG_MATCH_MANIFEST on its own.
shortcutQuery.setQueryFlags(LauncherApps.ShortcutQuery.FLAG_MATCH_DYNAMIC
        or LauncherApps.ShortcutQuery.FLAG_MATCH_MANIFEST
        or LauncherApps.ShortcutQuery.FLAG_MATCH_PINNED)
shortcutQuery.setPackage(packageName)

val shortcuts = try {
    launcherApps.getShortcuts(shortcutQuery, Process.myUserHandle())
} catch (e: SecurityException) {
    // This exception will be thrown if your app is not the default launcher
    Collections.emptyList<ShortcutInfo>()
}

// Lists all shortcuts from the query
shortcuts.forEach {
    Log.d(TAG, "Shortcut found ${it.`package`}, ${it.id}")
}

// Starts the first shortcut, as an example (this of course is not safe like this, 
// it will crash if the list is empty, etc).
val shortcut = shortcuts[0]
launcherApps.startShortcut(shortcut.`package`, shortcut.id, null, null, Process.myUserHandle())
```

This code assumes that you have a variable named `context` of type [`Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) and a variable named `packageName` of type `String` from somewhere.

---

Credits: This is all based on Quan Vu's work on this topic, his article [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/nhandling-shortcuts-when-building-an-android-launcher-5908d0bb50d2) and the corresponding repository [here](https://github.com/nongdenchet/Shortcuts).

Comment: Thank you very much